# setTimeout with The Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

In [Revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) of JavaScript how to use setTimeout function?

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwinkumark/Lrm3p/).

HTML: `<div id="container1"></div>`

JavaScript:

```
var classA = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    var names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
    var callTest = function() {
        for (var n in names) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                callTest2(names[n]);
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

    var callTest2 = function(pName) {
        $("#container1").append("In callTest   " + i+++" " + pName + "<br>");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            callTest2(pName)
        }, 10000)
    };

    return {
        testTheTest: function() {
            callTest();
        }
    }
})();

classA.testTheTest();
```

Framework: jQuery 1.5.2

When I execute the output is:

```
In callTest 0 f
In callTest 1 f
In callTest 2 f
In callTest 3 f
In callTest 4 f
In callTest 5 f
```

Instead of:

```
In callTest 0 a
In callTest 1 b
In callTest 2 c
In callTest 3 d
In callTest 4 e
In callTest 5 f
```

What am I missing? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: upvoted for your link to JS Patterns :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few slight modifications to your code which means it now works as you wish it to:

```
var classA = (function() {
    var i = 0,
        names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
        namesLength = names.length,
        callTest = function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                callTest2(0);
            }, 1000);
        },
        callTest2 = function(pIndex) {
            if (pIndex < namesLength) {
                var name = names[pIndex++];
                $("#container1").append("In callTest   " + i+++" " + name + "<br>");
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    callTest2(pIndex);
                }, 1000);
            }
        };

    return {
        testTheTest: function() {
            callTest();
        }
    }
})();

classA.testTheTest();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bTLLc/).

Comment: It would have been helpful if you listed out "why" you made the changes you did.

Answer (score 2):

cause the function insight setTimeout is calling not in that place, but after 1sec. And when it is called the n is equal to the last index. You have to make n global and increment each time the function is called

```
var classA = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    var names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
    var n = 0;
    var callTest = function() {
        for (var i in names) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                callTest2(names[n]);
                n++;
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

    var callTest2 = function(pName) {
        $("#container1").append("In callTest   " + i+++" " + pName + "<br>");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            callTest2(pName)
        }, 10000)
    };

    return {
        testTheTest: function() {
            callTest();
        }
    }
})();

classA.testTheTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   for (var n in names) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {                
                callTest2(names[n]);
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Code above is equivalent to below code.

```
    callTest2("f");
    callTest2("f");
    callTest2("f");
    callTest2("f");
    callTest2("f");
    callTest2("f");
```

Why..?
        Reason is function callTest2() is called after completion of one second, but before that whole names[] array is already iterated and "f" last character is passed to function callTest2.

For loop is iternated at very little fraction of micro-second. i.e. names[] array will be iterated in very little time. 
        At the end last character remains as "f" i.e. names[n].